# TypeScript: Any techniques to circuit-break a recursive conditional type inference?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, type-inference, conditional-types

I'm trying to type a function which takes an argument that reduces a series of items into one accumulated value. Here is a simplification of what I have:

```js
// A stub type for the items
interface Item { t: 'item'; }

function paginate<A>(reduce: (acc: A, item: Item, index: number) => A): Promise<A> {
  // ... stub for actual implementation ...
  return true as unknown as Promise<A>;
}
```

If I call this function, I don't get the type of inference that I desire. I'm hoping that when the return type of `reduce` is known, then the first argument (`acc`) should also be inferred to be that type.

```js
// expected: Promise<number>, inferred: Promise<{}>
const result = paginate((acc, item, index) => {
  acc; // expected: number, inferred: {}
  item; // expected: Item, inferred: Item
  index; // expected number, inferred: number

  return 5;
});
```

I tried using conditional types with inference to solve this problem, but all the variations I've tried have either failed because they don't constrain the generic type parameter for `acc` to anything specific or failed because the inference is recursive. I'm not totally sure.

```js
type Reducer<A> = (acc: A, item: Item, index: number) => A;
type Accumulator<Reduce> = Reduce extends (acc: infer A, item: Item, index: number) => infer A ? A : never;

// Probably too loose (using an any)
function paginateA<R extends Reducer<any>>(reduce: R): Promise<Accumulator<R>> {
  // ...
  return true as unknown as Promise<Accumulator<R>>;
}

// expected: Promise<number>, inferred: Promise<number>
const resultA = paginateA((acc, item, index) => {
  acc; // expected: number, inferred: any
  item; // expected: Item, inferred: Item
  index; // expected number, inferred: number

  return 5;
});

// Probably too recursive (tried to circuit-break with only inferring the return type first)
function paginateB<R extends Reducer<ReturnType<R>>>(reduce: R): Promise<Accumulator<R>> {
  // ...
  return true as unknown as Promise<Accumulator<R>>;
}

// expected: Promise<number>, inferred: Promise<any>
const resultB = paginateB((acc, item, index) => {
  acc; // expected: number, inferred: any
  item; // expected: Item, inferred: Item
  index; // expected number, inferred: number

  return 5;
});
```

Are there any techniques to "circuit-break" a recursive conditional type inference? I see [Anders mention that some class of recursive inference is okay](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496#issuecomment-363559872) (even though the quick-info will show the type as `any`), but I cannot understand the conditions under which this happens.

Is there some other technique I'm missing? `paginateA()` seems to work the best, because at least it got the type of `resultA` right. Is there some reason for that?

Here's a [playground with all the above code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEEFQZwFwVwEahgTwA4FNQDMD2AnZACywEsYMBbKAKABMMBjAGwEN8yA7C-bVxrAEkKlUAG9kALlAByclRkBuUAF8aNbHE6MYpXJ1BpWAc1KdWFADzgAfAAoOdOAOl3+jaeAA0oeZWnCVD5mDAAe0pxwlAgY+ACUoAC8NhBx0gAK+LiUpFAY1iliNKCgIKAAdJXQ8Eh4hPzwrMy+lGjMVBjcFnoGleXFoBzw+AYw+HBYrFCgWgDWnLgA7gZToJnZufm2ijRqNGUYoZg6GHQZWTl5lpHRsTbBnNixjucbV2IqNjSM+rCDGFA4MwYElDCYzBYMHY3IxGMERA8wglkuIBu5lAcjkwKGdQDcYvgHk98C9xGoSn4MWBDsccQEEb5Hs9TvSqAMQocqaAadjTniogSiczcfjYuoSkM4CNQABWHYqOI7GioTCgABKp2csQKoJhHgg8KorMoiMOEQFsWRKXAOxVWHAsKiQIsBEsGqcAhSiXVmoE3NCFE4dGmeukZmJBt8ImNpvC-Nu8SSKXDsQgoAA-GmIhgAG6xJVldYIVgIZgoZC4XCgZiVvKgOxwKBmYygVgrTgoOIaLQ6Hpg0zmCjgN3+wPBn0e7VtlA2eyOLXSNVpNYXTbWR2UZ0wV1q2eokplPoDSXSsYTVvTOYLZYXldvLYbrc72fy9SY2ksu+XfKi-D3RnEqS6zftcFp-t8vwghwgLApA3pGAOkLgNC7iGiajJIkm+6trCXI8icIpgUKJKftO7IiHhWIETGAHCsa7JBpypTUlROLxoKtEkYRCbiv8wwGHKuyKm+YBFiWZYVlWHCMFKTZ5vWYykHy26gIwpD4DJ5AALQIBwrCzKAizkEQoD6BJKYks2xBYCeozoFg2DqbAXaaNouj6P2EIUAAQiOhxjtM7pavgboYPxAAq9lurOc6+hgi7LsBa4OjJm5sNuIW7oUAyHpUx5hVKozjJMl6cPMSwrNMSVXClTrpc+NivvsLEfri1U-mB-4WUBq5XNOXw-JwfzQUCMDeaCCFeRg3kobCaGxla2Hosx-qteaCbEaSZEUhRK34XSoCBOh3WfkdDFhJRrXsbEm2fr+vG2bK8rCTQQA) to manipulate.

Comment: Hmm, in my preview of TS3.4 (using `typescript@next`) I get `Promise<number>` for `result` as expected, but I see in TS3.3 and below it is `Promise<{}>`.  Maybe just wait a few weeks?

Answer (score 2):

As I said, I think the particular inference of `A` from `Reducer<A>` you are trying to achieve might happen automatically in TypeScript 3.4 and up, but that hasn't been released yet.  For TypeScript 3.3 and below:

---

The particular technique I've seen used in cases like this where you want to say

```
declare function f<T extends Something<T>>(x: T): void; // circularity error or other issue
```

is to leave the generic `T` unconstrained, and place the constraint on the function parameter via an intersection:

```
declare function f<T>(x: T & Something<T>): void; // works now
```

I can't find canonical documentation for this, but the way I think this works is that when you call `f(x)`, the compiler tries to infer `T` from `x` of type `T & Something<T>`.  Since `x` is a `T & Something<T>`, it must be a `T`, from the way intersections work.  So the type of the `x` parameter is used as `T`.  Then it will check the interesection with `Something<T>` and if that doesn't work you get a compiler error.

Let's try it in your case, but before we do so, a big caveat: you probably can't get the compiler both to infer `paginate()`'s `R` type parameter from the value you pass in as `reduce`, *and* infer the parameter types of the value you pass in as `reduce` from the type of `R` inferred in the call to `paginate()`.  That is, either `R` will be *inferred* as `Reducer<number>` but you will have to *annotate* `(acc:number, item:Item, index:number)`... *or* you will have to *specify* `R` as `Reducer<number>` and the compiler will *infer* the types of `acc, item, index`.  You want it both ways, but I don't think the compiler is clever enough.  Or at least I can't make it happen.  So I'm going to assume for now that you're trying to infer `R` from a fully-annotated `reduce` callback:

```
interface Item {
  t: "item";
}

type Reducer<A> = (acc: A, item: Item, index: number) => A;
type Accumulator<Reduce> = Reduce extends Reducer<infer A> ? A : never;

declare function paginateC<R extends Reducer<any>>(
  reduce: R & Reducer<ReturnType<R>> // intersection here
): Promise<Accumulator<R>>;

// Promise<number> as desired
const resultC = paginateC((acc: number, item: Item, index: number) => 5);

// error, string is not number:
paginateC((x: number, y: Item, z: number)=>"string"); 

// okay, since string is a subtype of unknown
paginateC((x: unknown, y: Item, z: number)=>"string")

// also works with any
paginateC((x: any, y: Item, z: number)=>"string")
```

So that's fine.

---

Back up to the problem with inferring `acc, item, index`...  You can always specify `R` like this:

```
// acc, item, index inferred from specified R
paginateC<Reducer<number>>((acc, item, index) => 5);
```

but you don't want to do that.

In truth, I wouldn't expect the compiler to narrow the `acc` parameter down to your desired `A` since function parameters can always be widened safely ([contravariance of function parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strictFunctionTypes)).  The compiler will probably leave `acc` as something wide like `{}`, `unknown`, or `any` unless you annotate it or specify `R` manually as above.

I *am* a little surprised that it doesn't narrow `item` and `index` down to `Item` and `number` respectively instead of leaving them as `any`.  But there's probably not much to be done, since it is a [known limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26418) of type inference that it doesn't happen in multiple passes.  Oh well.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this thorough exploration into type narrowing and the various tradeoffs! It sounds like you're referring to some specific changes in TypeScript 3.4, would you mind pointing out which changes you think might enable inference in the way I've been looking for?

Comment: I'm referring to the behavior of my compiler when I use TypeScript 3.4-dev, so I don't know specifically what change causes it to start inferring properly.  Looking at the merged pull requests after 3.3 I see that [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29478) has to do with inference of generics and contextual types, so it might be that one.  But that's just a guess.